# Непонятки с doctrine

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine2

Привет всем!

Вот у меня такая сущность

```
/**
 * @Entity()
 * @Table(name="rules")
 */
class TagRule
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer", name="id")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer", name="tag_id")
     * */
    public $tagId;

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer", name="value_code")
     */
    public $valueCode;
}
```

Сейчас добавил зависимость, или как правильнее говорить?

Вот так

```
/**
 * @Entity()
 * @Table(name="rules")
 */
class TagRule
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer", name="id")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer", name="tag_id")
     * */
    public $tagId;

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer", name="value_code")
     */
    public $valueCode;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Tag")
     * @JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $tag;
}
```

Но почему-то теперь при добавлении записи в таблицу rules поле tag_id принимает значение null.

Не могу понять почему. С доктриной знаком недавно.

Comment: Покажите, как вы привязываете Tag к TagRule.

Comment: @svgrafov вот в Tag я ничего не делал. :)

Comment: Ну значит TagRule к Tag.

Comment: @svgrafov Извините, это как? Можно тыкнуть? :) Был бы очень вам признателен

Comment: `$tagRule->addTag($tag)` - что-то в этом духе. Как в [документации](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html) по связям(они же relationships, associations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TagRule` должен выглядеть так:

```
/**
 * @Entity()
 * @Table(name="rules")
 */
class TagRule
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer", name="id")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;

    /**
     * @Column(type="integer", name="value_code")
     */
    public $valueCode;

    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="Tag")
     * @JoinColumn(name="tag_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $tag;

    public function addTag(Tag $tag)
    {
        $this->tag = $tag;
    }
}
```

А `Tag` - так:

```
/**
 * @Entity()
 * @Table(name="tags")
 */
class Tag
{
    /**
     * @Id
     * @Column(type="integer", name="id")
     * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    public $id;


    /**
     * @OneToOne(targetEntity="TagRule")
     * @JoinColumn(name="tagrule_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $tagRule;
}
```

Добавлять `Tag` к `TagRule` нужно так:

```
$tag = new Tag;
$rule = new TagRule;
$rule->addTag($tag);
```

Обратите внимание на то, что вам не нужно объявлять свойство `tagId` в колонке БД `tag_id`. Это сделает Doctrine.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Ваше решение помогло мне разобраться.